# Blazor refresh page is slow when making any changes in the components

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server project with about 100 pages(.razor), and 10 Razor Pages (.cshtml), When I make a change in a .cshtml page it takes about 3 seconds to refresh page and show the results but when I make a change in a Blazor page it takes about 12 seconds to refresh page and show the results in browser.

- All pages has the same .js and .css references
- It seems, the more Blazor pages I have, the slower it gets

What is wrong? Does it show that Blazor is not suitable for large project with lots of pages?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/15264

Comment: Are you using WASM?

Comment: No Blazor Server